# Quarkus: MDC is not exposed in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, logback, slf4j, azure-application-insights, quarkus

how do I get the MDC information to show up in Azure Insights.
Currently I only see it in the trace log.

I am using:

1. Quarkus 1.13.0.Final
2. Application Insights 3.0

I have inserted the Application Insights according to these instructions => [Java codeless application monitoring Azure Monitor Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent)

**Source Code**

```java
...
import org.slf4j.MDC;


@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class DemoRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String DEMO_TAG = "demoTag";

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext context) {
        MDC.put(DEMO_TAG, "myDemoTag");
  
    }

}
```

**application.yaml**

```yaml
log:
    console:
      format: "%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) requestDemoTag=[%X{demoTag}]  %s%e%n"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello! I wanted to reach out and see if you ever found a solution for this. Manually adding a JAR file and modifying the JRE settings seems a little sketchy to me. Hoping that someone had found a simpler way to export logs to Azure Monitor from a Quarkus app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you can only see MDC information in this place? And what's your target?

[image]

=============================UPDATE==============================

I'll share my configuration on the project. If we need to add appinsights java agent to our program, we could follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent).

First, download the jar file mentioned in the tutorial you can save it in your workspace, I stored it in the path:D:/applicationinsights-agent-3.0.2.jar

Then I created a file 'applicationinsights.json' in the same folder as jar file. In the json file, I set the connection string of the azure application insights instance. [Creating a new application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-new-resource#sign-in-to-microsoft-azure) then I can get the connection string in the overview page.

Next, I need to set the jvm args. I used sts as the ide, so Menu bar-> Window-> Preference-> Java-> Installed JREs-> double click the one you used-> Default vm arguments set vaule `-Xmx512m -XX:+UseG1GC -javaagent:D:/applicationinsights-agent-3.0.2.jar`

[image]
[image]

Adding the MDC code and starting the program, then I can get the result in the top of my answer.

If you need to deploy your program into azure app service, [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview#supported-environments-languages-and-resource-providers) said agent appinsights hasn't supported app service, but I find [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67055865/14574199) which proved to be ok of this feature. That says

> Enable application insights for the app service and specify an app
> insights instance and Add this application setting;
> XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Java -> 1

**Let's see log4j2 configuration in my side.**

[image]
[image]

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="FATAL">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="pattern">%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) requestDemoTag=[%X{demoTag}]  %s%e%n</Property>
        <Property name="logPath">logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I only see the MDC information in the StackTrace. Like on the left picture of your example. Unfortunately, I don't see the MDC information in Azure. Also not in the custom properties. My goal is that the MDC information is played out in the custom properties.

Comment: Thanks for response sir, I've updated my answer and share my configuration. If you have further questions, pls feel free to add comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have implemented all the steps described. My service is also detected in Azure Application Insights. Even when I set environment variables in applicationsinsights.json this variable is shown in CustomProperties. Only the MDC information is not displayed

Comment: I've added my configurations on log4j2, maybe you can compare it with yours and get some finding.

Comment: Thank you for the log4j2 settings. With the SpringBoot project, the MDC is also displayed in Azure Application Insights. However, not for the Quarkus project. So I think it is a problem between Quarkus, sl4j and Azure Application Insights. Somewhere the MDC information gets lost

Comment: I'm sorry for it and I really know little about Quarkus, I'm afraid there's bug exist. Maybe you can try to use java sdk sir.

Comment: No problem. But thanks for your help. When I have a solution, I will post this here